# How to encode Japanese characters in xsd:base64Binary field in XML

Tags: xml, unicode, encoding, character-encoding, base64

I am trying to compose an XML document that will get sent to some target system. (There isn't a particular system, I'm just trying to implement a messaging standard.)  The document schema gives the type of a particular field as xsd:base64Binary.  No problem, I just base64-encode the content of the field when serializing.  But what if the original value of the field contains Unicode characters?  In my case I'm dealing with Japanese characters.

The programming language I'm using represents these characters internally with their Unicode values. Ex:

> "た" (HIRAGANA LETTER TA) = 0x305F.

So before I can base64-encode this value I need a way to transform it from a double-wide byte to a series of single-width bytes. UTF-8 encoding comes to mind, so the value would become:

> 0xE3 0x81 0x9F

This base64-encodes to:

> 44Gf

So presumably that's what would go in my document.  There's just one wrinkle to this.  The system that is receiving the XML document will have to "know" somehow that the base64-decoded value of the field is UTF-8 encoded.  I can't find anything in the standard for the messaging format that says that once the value of the field is base64-decoded, the resulting value is UTF-8 (or any other format) encoded.  I was hoping the correct thing to do in this scenario is described in the XML spec, but I haven't been able to find anything definitive.

One thought that comes to mind is that maybe the character encoding of the base64-decoded value is supposed to be the same as the character encoding named in the XML prolog, for example:

> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

So if my XML document has this, then is the receiving system supposed to know that once the field in question is base64-decoded, that it is still UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Why would a binary field contain Unicode text?  It wouldn't need to be base64-encoded because XML can handle UTF-8-encoded Unicode text just fine.  A binary field should contain....binary, and base64-encoding would be used because XML doesn't support binary.  You are correct that the other end would need to know that the field was double-encoded to process it correctly.  The XML encoding wouldn't control how the field was double-encoded.  It would have to be part of the spec.